# Are there two separate versions of Hugo Stiglitz's background in Inglourious Basterds?

Tags: dialogue, alternate-version, inglourious-basterds

I've seen *[Inglourious Basterds](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0361748/)* a few times.  I recall that the Samuel L. Jackson voice over, which gave a background of Hugo Stiglitz, stated

> As a German enlisted man, he managed to kill thirteen Gestapo officers; mostly Majors.

Upon subsequent viewings the "*mostly Majors*" part was dropped.  I have confirmed that I have heard both lines correctly.

Are there two separate versions of *Inglourious Basterds*?

If so, what are other notable changes?

Comment: How have you confirmed the first part, if later viewings didn't have it?

Comment: I saw some citations on the [wiki page of the character](http://inglouriousbasterds.wikia.com/wiki/Hugo_Stiglitz) backing his question, I have only heard the part without the majors in the movie.

Comment: Yes. Here is a reference that include the "mostly majors" line. http://inglouriousbasterds.wikia.com/wiki/Hugo_Stiglitz

Comment: Would be wrong anyway. In the newspaper you can read at least 8 ranks that are not Major.

Comment: That might explain the edited version in which the reference to "Majors" was deleted.  It does not answer the overall question.

Comment: Could have been a Jackson ad lib, taken out after someone noticed the newspaper.